# Javascript always taking old value instead of updated value of Textbox in ASP.NET Update panel?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, textbox

I have a update panel and there are three textboxes. When clicking on a button (in another update panel), the backend calculates some code and sets the textboxes to a new value. After that, there is a javascript call for a graph and the javascript function always takes the default value given in HTML and not the updated value (even if the textboxes are updated!!) and even if I make a call like this:

```
txtLabels.Text = labelData;
txtFail.Text = dataFail;
txtPass.Text = dataPass;
panelScript.Update();
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, GetType(), "Javascript", "StartChart(); ", true);
resultPanel.Update();
```

Panelscript is the update panel where the textboxes are and resultpanel is the update panel where the graph is.

Ideas?

Comment: I don't understand - you are trying to run clientside code on the server side.  Why not do it all client side and if you need to do server side processing, then make an ajax call.  Also, not sure if you can register a script block in an update panel, wouldn't you need to register it on page load?

Comment: There is a lot of data from the database which I take and have to calculate some numbers. After that I set the new values to the textboxes and want to show the graph with the new updated values, the graph shows after all but with old values (even if in the textboxes are new values).

Comment: Ok so you are probably better doing an ajax call to a handler to get your updated values rather than trying to run this in an update panel.  As I said you are trying to mix your server side and client side processing.  If you want to continue down that route, you would need some script in your update panel that fired when it loaded, just registering a script block doesn't mean it will run